# Por qué ($event.target.value) no recibe la info en Angular8 y MySQL?

Tags: angular, select, dropdownlist

($event.target.value)

```
<div class="select is-small is-fullwidth" [formGroup]="createAccountForm">
<select class="form-control" name="ConContryName" formControlName="country"  (change)="onChangeCountry($event.target.value)">
    <option value="">Select Country...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="countryId">{{country.countryName}}</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="select is-small is-fullwidth" [formGroup]="createAccountForm">
<select class="form-control" name="ConStateName" formControlName="state"  (change)="onChangeState($event.target.value)">
    <option value="">Select State...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="stateId">{{state.stateName}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

```js
urlDB = 'http://localhost:3000/';

getCountries() {
  return this.httpClient.get(`${this.urlDB}superadmin/getCountries`);
};

getStates(countryId: number) {
  return this.httpClient.get(`${this.urlDB}superadmin/getStates/${countryId}`);
}

onChangeCountry(countryId: number ) {
  if (countryId) {
    alert(countryId);               //the alert works, but the value of countryId is UNDEFINED
    this.countryStateCityService.getStates(countryId).subscribe(data => {
      this.states = data;
      this.municipalities = null;
    });
  } else {
    this.states = null;
    this.municipalities = null;
  }
}


urlDB = 'http://localhost:3000/';

  getCountries() {
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.urlDB}superadmin/getCountries`);
  };

  getStates(countryId: number) {
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.urlDB}superadmin/getStates/${countryId}`);
  }

  getMunicipalities(stateId: number) {
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.urlDB}superadmin/getMunicipalities/${stateId}`);
  }
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <div class="select is-small is-fullwidth" [formGroup]="createAccountForm">
    <select class="form-control" name="ConContryName" formControlName="country"  (change)="onChangeCountry($event.target.value)">
      <option value="">Select Country...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="countryId">{{country.countryName}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control">
  <div class="select is-small is-fullwidth" [formGroup]="createAccountForm">
    <select class="form-control" name="ConStateName" formControlName="state"  (change)="onChangeState($event.target.value)">
      <option value="">Select State...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="stateId">{{state.stateName}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hola, estoy usando Angular - node js - mysql... estoy haciendo un select dropdown de países, y después otro select de estados y así con municipios; esta info está en un DB de MySQL. el código funciona cuando obtengo la lista de los paises pero en `onChangeCountry($event.target.value)` de mi HTML me da un valor `UNDEFINED`, puedo entrar en el `alert` de `onChangeCountry()` pero el `console.log(countryId)` muestra UNDEFINED.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the spanish version of SO, you must translate your question to the lenguage of this site or your question will be removed

Comment: Te tengo la respuesta, pero serie bueno que tradujeras primero al español.

Comment: Gracias Angel... estoy entrando en el mundo de la programación y apenas vi que estoy en una sección en español.

Answer (score 1):

En esta linea:

```
<option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="stateId">{{state.stateName}}</option>
```

`[value]="stateId"` es indefinido por que no existe en ningun lado. Asumiendo que la estructura de de `states` contuviera `Id` esto `[value]="stateId"` debería ser `[value]="state.Id"`.

Infiero que es un objeto por esta linea: `{{state.stateName}}`.

Comment: tengo una tabla de countries con countryId, countryName y countryKey, tengo otra tabla de states con stateId, stateName, stateKey y countryId, y otra de municipios. No creo que el nombre Id de stateId me afecte... o si? me viene la duda... pero ni siquiera llega a definir el countryId del primer select... imagino que si es correcto lo que me comentas, será el sieugiente problema.... pero ahorita mi inconveniente es conseguir countryId. También hay código que no coloqué para no hacerlo tan largo.

Comment: Puedes publicar la la estructura de `state`?. Debe ser un objeto. Para poder darte una explicación mejor. Actualiza la pregunta con esos nuevos datos.